# Problems with booting on recovery mode

Tags: grub2, bios, recovery-mode

I want to access my recovery mode because I have problems with my nvidia drivers. But I don't get a chance to use my shift key because I have a black screen for 10 seconds (when I boot my pc) and the next screen that I get is the screen with the Linux Mint emblem on.

I first though that I didn't get a screen from my motherboard because my pc stood in Fast Boot but I've reset my cmos and now I'm sure it isn't.

What should I do?

Comment: Normally to get into the BIOS screen you have to press a key as the machine is just starting to boot. It's a different key for different BIOSs, but Delete is normally a good try, otherwise the F keys (often F10 or F12)

Comment: Well I can't access my bios because I don't get a screen from my motherboard. I have to disable fast boot to get this screen when I boot my pc.

Comment: Besides you using Mint this has nothing to do with the operating system at all. Not related to Ubuntu. And yes you do regarding the comment... you probably need either another key to enter it or need to be quicker.

Comment: I know for sure that "del" the key is to enter my bios, so when I boot my pc. I start pressing the "del" button and my screen stays black.

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases **so Mint is off-topic here as well.** However, on http://unix.stackexchange.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling fast boot, you can un-hide GRUB. Note that this will also show all the boot messages instead of showing the Mint splash screen. In a terminal:

`sudo -e /etc/default/grub`

Comment out (put a hash in front of) the line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`. Also change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`, assuming you don't have any other options in there. If you do, remove `quiet splash` but it's up to you to make sure the options are valid.

Exit the editor with Ctrl-X, Y, Enter, then `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Thanks I've done what you said, but how can I go from grub to recovery mode?

Comment: On boot, there should be options for Mint and Advanced options. Select Advanced options, then select recovery mode for the latest kernel you have.

Comment: I can't choose between options, I just see a list with things en drivers that are being loaded. I can't go to the GNU grub

Comment: That's weird. Is GRUB_TIMEOUT something reasonable like 5 or 10 so that you have a chance?

Comment: Well I have a black screen until a list of drivers and programs start to activate, and my shift key to go to the Gnu grub menu doesn't work

Comment: You did run `sudo update-grub`, right? I have no idea why it isn't doing anything.